# Попытка перезаписать ячейку в Excel xlwt

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlrd

Доброго времени суток дамы и господа. Есть код

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('bk1.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

# time - это время от 9 до 18 в строку
time1 = [sheet.cell_value(0, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]
# name - это имена людей в столбец
name = [sheet.cell_value(row, 0) for row in range(sheet.nrows)]

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

for index, value in enumerate(name):
# Здесь 0 отвечает в какой строке он будет находится
# Перемещая index и 0 можно указать как он будет отображатся либо столбец либо строка
sheet.write(index, 0, value)

for index, value in enumerate(time1):
# Здесь 0 отвечает в какой строке он будет находится
# Перемещая index и 0 можно указать как он будет отображатся либо столбец либо строка
sheet.write(0, index, value)



workbook.save('output.xls')
```

Вопрос:
1) Как сделать так чтобы две данные не соприкасались?

Comment: Вы можете задать более понятный вопрос? Я не понимаю что значит `"чтобы две данные не соприкасались"` ...

Comment: После запуска скрипта, консоль выводит ошибку перезаписи ячейки (0, 0)